# Request not hitting spring boot embeded server through tomcat and browser

Tags: api, rest, postman

Am trying to hit my rest API in spring boot with the embeded server configured  through browser and postman, but the request doesn't hit the server and am getting 404-not found am pretty new to springboot , please help me in this as in what to check further so that i can test my rest API

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to couple of reasons

**Try the following**

1. Ensure the port you are specifying is correct
2. Ensure the end point you are specifying exist
3. Ensure the request you are sending is of correct REST action type (GET,POST etc)
4. Ensure your controller class is available in the same package in which Application class `(with @SpringBootAnnotation`) exists, else you will have to use `@ComponentScan` to make sure your controller class is scanned and endpoints available to receive traffic

Most likely, above should help :) If not, you'll need to describe what is done in the application so far